# Tags related to [tag] include [tag]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, related-tags

So, when you go to the top-users section of a tag, it will show you some related tags. But it will also show you the tag you're looking at (see image). I fail to see why this would be intended behavior.

[image: Tags related to blogger]

Comment: I fail to see why it is a pr0bl3m that needs to be fixed. You could write an userscript that hides the first element in the related tags div.

Comment: There's probably a synonym (e.g. `blogger-platform`) which gets resolved to and displayed as `blogger`. But that wouldn't make sense, because the numbers match exactly.

Comment: @rene it's pretty useless to display that X is related to X when X itself is already displayed above.

Comment: @CodeCaster nah, it happens on all tags, on all sites, including child metas

Comment: Maybe so that you can compare, out of blogger's 1657 questions, 434 of them are about HTML.

Comment: @zondo But why show `[blogger]` and `1657` twice? Is it useful to duplicate content? Is it useful to duplicate content?

Comment: @zondo Also, it's not consistent with the tag info page—for example on the [`[blogger]` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/blogger/info) the "Related tags" list doesn't contain `[blogger]`.

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed back in 2018 - thanks for the report!