# "Related tags" sidebar lists tags as related to themselves

Tags: bug, tags, new-nav, user-interface

Here's a minor UI issue I just noticed: when filtering questions by tag on SO, the sidebar redundantly list the tag(s) being filtered by as "related tags", as in this screenshot (look under the mouse cursor):

[image: Screenshot]

(Also, as shown at the bottom of the screenshot, actually clicking one of these redundant "related tag" links triggers [a different UI bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300264/hot-network-questions-not-expanding-after-changing-tag-filter) that causes the "more hot questions" link at the end of the HNQ sidebar to stop working.  However, that's a separate bug, and can be triggered in other ways as well.)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Opt in to the [new navigation interface](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), if you haven't done that already.
2. Visit a tag page (say, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)) on SO.  Verify that the top of the page looks like this (new nav):

   > [image: Screenshot of [java] tag page under new SO navigation]

   and not like this (old nav):

   > [image: Screenshot of [java] tag page under old SO navigation]
3. Observe that the "java" tag itself is redundantly listed as the first "related tag" in the sidebar.

This does not happen with [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) turned off.  Thus, I would consider this a regression in the new navigation interface.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: @4castle: How so? When you click the [tag:java] link above, do you not see the [java] tag in the sidebar under "Related Tags"?

Comment: For me it shows, [android], [swing], [spring], [eclipse], [hibernate], etc. It looks pretty much the same as your screenshot, just no [java].

Comment: Huh, looks like you need to have opted in to the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) to see this bug. I didn't realize that was actually still not enabled for everybody.

Comment: @4castle: When you look at the top of the [tag:java] page, does it look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHCzb.png) or [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtQeJ.png)? If the former, you're still using the old nav; if the latter, you're using the new nav.

Comment: Ah, I was using the old nav. I can reproduce it now.

Comment: To be fair, it's not _wrong_.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Related post  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334264/tags-related-to-tag-include-tag

Comment: @BhargavRao: That one seems to be about the old nav, and about [a specific tag subpage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blogger/topusers). So it's similar, but not quite a dupe AFAICT.

Comment: What are "related tags" on "/questions" actually related to?